# Sheaf commutes with limits

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory

There is such statement:

> Presheaf $\mathfrak F$ is a sheaf if it commutes with limits:
>   $$\mathfrak F(\lim_{\to} U_\alpha)=\lim_{\gets}\mathfrak F(U_\alpha).$$

Can you rewrite this formula more exactly using following definitions.

Let $\Phi : \mathfrak J \to \mathfrak C$ is a functor between two categories.

**Definition 1.** Direct limit of $\Phi$ is an object $X\in\mathfrak C$ which represent functor
$${\mathfrak C}^0\longrightarrow Sets$$
$$Y\longmapsto\hom_{Funct(\mathfrak J,\mathfrak C)}(\Delta Y, \Phi),$$
where $\Delta : \mathfrak C\to Funct(\mathfrak J,\mathfrak C)$ be a diagonal functor.

**Definition 2.** Analogically inverse limit corepresent functor
$$\mathfrak C\longrightarrow Sets$$
$$Y\longmapsto\hom_{Funct(\mathfrak J,\mathfrak C)}(\Phi,\Delta Y).$$

**Definition 3.** At last presheaf on space $M$ is a functor from category of open subsets of $M$.

Answer (score 5):

The statement is false. But it is correct that a sheaf is a presheaf which preserves a *certain class* of colimits. See also my answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23268).

Comment: It's quite irritating that this myth keeps showing up. I wonder where it comes from?